# How can I use Objective-C extension functions in Swift with XCode 12.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

As shown in the following screenshots, I have an NSString extension in Objective-C which is called in Swift. 
Recently, I used XCode 11.7 and it worked completely fine. Then I updated XCode to 12.2 and this error appeared. I tried again with XCode 11.7 and it still worked fine.
It seems to only happen to Objective-C Extension functions because the rest of the Objective-C classes can be used normally in the Swift codes. In the bridging header file, at line 14, the "UIImage+Overlay.h" also has the same issue.
How can I use Objective-C Extension in Swift codes with XCode 12.2?

[image]


[image]


[image]

Comment: i would place the bridging header import rule at the first line for `#import "NSString+CSV.h"`, minimum one line earlier than `#import "CSVConverter.h"`. If this does not make it better, writing the extension in swift.

Comment: I've tested on XCode 12.1 and 12.2 and it works OK so try to clean up and rebuild your project.